# PL/SQL DB triggers - Make insertion fail if a given condition is not met

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a small test database I'm using for learning SQL.
There's a `Duel` table, which contains two `Pilot` foreign keys (the duelists). I want to check if the duelists haven't already "met" before insertion.

Pseudocode:

```
before insertion on Duel
for each row already in the table
  if ((new_row.numpilot1 = old_row.numpilot1 and new_row.numpilot2 = old_row.numpilot2) OR
      (new_row.numpilot1 = old_row.numpilot2 and new_row.numpilot2 = old_row.numpilot1)
     )
    insertion fails
```

One other alternative would be

```
tempnum integer;
select numpilot1 into tempnum from duel 
where (:NEW.numpilot1 = numpilot1 and :NEW.numpilot2 = numpilot2) OR
      (:NEW.numpilot1 = numpilot2 and :NEW.numpilot2 = numpilot1);

if tempnum == null
    fail insertion
```

What is the PL/SQL (Oracle DBMS) version of this?

Comment: Given that Oracle's most famous supplied table is called DUAL, I fear the name of your app's main table is a recipe for confusion and perhaps disaster.

Comment: Eh, like I said, this is just a test DB, there's no app at all. Not a problem, but thanks for that comment, I'll be sure to keep that in mind for production systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't use a trigger for this sort of requirement.  Instead, you'd create a couple of constraints on the table.  I would suggest a unique constraint on (`numpilot1`, `numpilot2`) along with a check constraint that ensures that `numpilot1 < numpilot2`.

```
ALTER TABLE duel
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_pilot_combination
          UNIQUE( numpilot1, numpilot2 );

ALTER TABLE duel
  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_pilot1_lt_pilot2
           CHECK( numpilot1_fk < numpilot2_fk );
```

If you wanted to do this sort of thing in a trigger, it would be quite a bit more complicated.  In general, a row-level trigger on `DUEL` cannot query the `DUEL` table-- doing so would create a mutating table exception.  You would need to create a collection in a package, a before statement trigger that initializes the collection, a row-level trigger that inserts the new pilot keys into the collection, and an after statement trigger that reads the data in the collection and does the validation.  That's quite a few moving pieces to manage in addition to the potential performance hit.  If you're really stuck with the trigger solution, however, there is an example of [using the three trigger solution to work around mutating table exceptions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/MutatingTableExceptions.php) on Tim Hall's site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm folowing a guide which specifies I must do this with a trigger. Perhaps there's an easier way to do what I want w/o iterating through the table, for example? I don't care about performance, all of this is purely academic. Thanks again.

Comment: Please check my new alternative, perhaps it's more doable. Thanks.

Comment: @FranciscoP - the guide you are following is either written by a nincompoop or is not intended to be implemented on an Oracle database.  Constraints (or Tony's function-based index which is logically the same) is the only sensible solution.  It's not just a matter of performance, it's also *correctness*.  The trigger based solution won't work in a multi-user environment.

Comment: @Francisco- The problem is that a row-level trigger on `DUEL` cannot generally query the `DUEL` table without creating a mutating table exception.  That's why you need the combination of multiple triggers if you're really stuck with the trigger approach.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a function-based index:

```
create unique index duel_uk on duel
( least(numpilot1, numpilot2), greatest(numpilot1, numpilot2));
```

The answer you are clearly seeking is a trigger like this:

```
create trigger duel_trg
before insert on duel
for each row
declare
  dummy number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into dummy
  from duel
  where (numpilot1 = :new.numpilot1 and numpilot2 = :new.numpilot2)
  or (numpilot1 = :new.numpilot2 and numpilot2 = :new.numpilot1);

  if dummy > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'You lose');
  end if;
end;
```

However, that will fail to ensure integrity in a multi-user (or multi-session) environment, as this can happen:

```
User1> insert into duel (numpilot1, numpilot2) values (1,2);
-- trigger checks, all seems OK

User2> insert into duel (numpilot1, numpilot2) values (1,2);
-- trigger checks, all seems OK (can't see User1's new row
-- as it hasn't been committed)

User1> commit;
User2> commit;
```

Result: corrupt database.  So while this trigger may satisfy the teacher, it is a bad solution and constraints should be used instead (preferably Justin's solution rather than mine!)

Comment: Let me be honest, your answer was the one I took, but Justin Cave's answer is, all in all, better and taught me a lot of stuff I should take into account when dealing with "serious" databases, therefore I will accept his answer, but not before thanking you a lot for the time you dedicated. You have my upvote.

Comment: And just to point it out, if your INSERT statement were to use the INSERT ... SELECT syntax, the trigger would raise the exception ORA-04091: table DUEL is mutating rather than actually attempting to do the validation you want.